# Maximize Possible Subset Sums of A Multiset

Tags: backtracking

The following problem is a problem I faced in one of my coding competitions.

> Given two positive integers $N$, $M$. You can have $M$ distinct types of stones, for which different types of stones must have different weights. Find the maximum of $k$ such that any weight in $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$ can be formed as a total weight with at most N stones, given that you can choose the weights of those $M$ types of stones. (Assume that any type of stones have infinitely many, but each time you could only choose N stones among all stones in all types.)

For example, when $(N, M)=(2, 2)$, if we choose the stones to have weights $\{1, 2\}$, we can form 3 with 1 and 2 and we can form 4 with 2 and 2, so we'll have 4.

When $(N, M)=(3, 2)$, $k_{max}=7$. Since we can choose the weights $\{1, 3\}$, and form 4 with 1 and 3, 5 with 1 and 1 and 3, 6 with 3 and 3, and 7 with 3 and 3 and 1. It's also given that when $(N, M)=(5, 4)$, $k_{max}=71$.

This problem seems familiar to me at first, but even till now I haven't solved it. The problem states that $1\leq N\leq8$ and $1\leq M\leq6$. Does that mean there might not be a good polynomial solution? Is this problem related to efficient backtracking?

I appreciate any kind of help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PålGD There are infinitely many stones for each time but each time you could only choose **N stones** among all stones in all types.

Comment: You could use more than 1 stone in a single type for each time. Just note that each selection the *maximum* number of *total stones* is N.

Comment: Okay, now I understand.

Comment: @Inuyashayagami Yeah, that's a typo. Thanks for reminding!!!

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the number system (by number system I mean decimal, binary, etc). I guess the answer is the following: if $N \le M$, then we should use powers of $2$. Otherwise, let $a=N - M + 2$, then the numbers are $1, a, a \cdot 2, a \cdot 4$, etc. It's only a guess: you can write a brute-force solution for smaller values of $M$ to check that this works (I think it should be feasible for $M \le 4$). Actually, you can just run brute-force for some time (if you implement it efficiently I think you compute answers for all $N$ and $M$ within an hour).

Comment: @Dmitry But even applying brute-force seems difficult since all weights can be chosen by us and maybe for each selection we have to iterate through all possible combinations to find K for each selection. That's seems to be a time-consuming method.